# Scroll position jumps if DOM is changed while elastic scroll is bouncing

Tags: javascript, macos, webkit, scroll, browser-bugs

On OS X, user can scroll past the viewport, and the browser will bounce the page.
As user, I like this effect, but it causes an unfortunate bug in our website.

When user clicks a large “Next Article” banner on the bottom of a page, next article is loaded and most DOM on the page is replaced. When this happens, I reset scroll position to the top:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

This usually works fine. However if user manages to click “Next Article” **while the browser is bouncing the page due to elastic scroll**, `scrollTo` doesn't work properly. It seems that after replacing most of the DOM and resetting scroll position, some remaining events from the bouncing effect “arrive” and make scrolling jump a screen or two below **after** it has been reset to zero.

How do I force the browser to scroll to the beginning and ignore leftover bouncing events?
This happens on WebKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to fix the issue, so as a workaround I wrote a function that returns a promise. This promise is resolved when elastic scroll is finished.

When user clicks “Next Article”, I load the article but I wait until promise is resolved before I perform DOM operations and call `scrollTo`. This works well for me.

```
function waitForElasticScroll() {

  // If user scrolls part viewport and clicks while elastic scroll
  // has not fully "returned", scroll position will get messed up in Chrome.

  // Our workaround is to wait for elastic scroll to finish before transitioning.
  // rAF calls help avoid unnecessary layout.

  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      var maxScrollY = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;

      function isReady() {
        var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
        return scrollY <= maxScrollY;
      }

      function resolveIfReady() {
        if (isReady()) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(resolveIfReady);
        }
      }

      resolveIfReady();

    });
  });
}
```

I'm using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for Promises and [animation-frame](http://github.com/kof/animation-frame) for rAF polyfill.